# if the number IS less than 0 or IS equal to 1

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Do need to write "is" twice?

> if the number IS less than 0 or IS equal to 1

or single "is" is enough:

> if the number IS less than 0 or equal to 1

Answer (score 2):

You can write this either way, the single "is" is more fluid, a little smoother.

Comment: Thank you! By "fluid" do you mean that the single "is" is more preferable than double "is"?

Comment: “fluid” means that the sentence has a more natural flow; the second *is*, in such a simple sentence, can be awkward.